# how to convert above crystal synax to basic syntax in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a report I am trying to modify in Crystal. It has a data field that has a formula in it, but I want to use another formula.

how to convert above crystal synax to basic syntax in crystal report

```
IIF ({rpl_bal_bundlelabels.recordcode} = "2",0 ,
IIF ({rpl_bal_bundlelabels.StdOdd} = "OS",
IIF ({rpl_bal_bundlelabels.totalsupply} > {rpl_bal_bundlelabels.standard},
IIF (({rpl_bal_bundlelabels.totalsupply} mod {rpl_bal_bundlelabels.standard}) > 0,
{rpl_bal_bundlelabels.totalsupply} - (({rpl_bal_bundlelabels.totalsupply} \    
{rpl_bal_bundlelabels.standard}) * {rpl_bal_bundlelabels.standard}) ,
{rpl_bal_bundlelabels.standard} ) ,{rpl_bal_bundlelabels.totalsupply} ) ,
{rpl_bal_bundlelabels.BundleCopies} ) )
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new formula
2. paste the text
3. correct the syntax, if necessary
4. set the result to `formula =`